# How to force flatpak to ask for a password

Tags: sudo, password, flatpak, discover-software-center

When installing a flatpak that will be installed globally anyone in the `sudo` group can install  a flatpak without `sudo`.

Is there a way to either edit the polkit rules that are installed by flatpak to allow this or to just remove it altogether so that any time you try to install a global flatpak you will be prompted for a password using both the CLI and the Software Store (in my case KDE Discover)?

Comment: I renamed that file along with another one, but it made no difference. My test was on adding the Flathub repo - that actually worked after I renamed the .pkla. However, I cannot disable Flatpak's ability to install software if the user is in the sudo group. Alas, my answer is worthless.

Comment: ahh thanks for trying.  I'm sure there is a way to edit one or both of those files to stop this behavior.  I'm assuming that someone knows how to edit those files, the wiki page was written assuming that you already knew how those type of permissions worked and gave examples and some very general instructions.. @ajgringo619

Comment: Editing the files is one thing, but deleting/moving them should have stopped this behavior. One thing I did that kind of mitigated this issue was to delete the system repo and install the user one; that way, my user can only install Flatpaks in my home directory.

Comment: @ajgringo619 that would be a way to at least mitigate it.  How did you do that? --user XXX  when using add-if-missing... command?     Weird that deleting the files did not revert the behavior.  I would imagine that editing the files to change the rules to require the password is possible, I'm still holding out hope that some who knows will answer.  (as an aside it seems like a stupid security hole, yea app are supposed to be sandboxed but only if the dev doesn't change the permissions.  You cannot acces root w/o a pass for a reason on Linux...)

Comment: `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists --user flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`

Comment: Added your tag!

Answer (score 1):

By default, flatpak polkit rules do not require a password. You can however set up rules to require one.

### Ubuntu/Debian derivatives (*`policykit` < 0.106*)

Create a new file named `flatpak‑sudo‑always‑password.pkla` in `/⁠etc⁠/⁠polkit‑1⁠/⁠localauthority⁠/⁠50‑local.d⁠/`

```ini
[Install Flatpak apps and runtimes]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.Flatpak.app-install;org.freedesktop.Flatpak.runtime-install;org.freedesktop.Flatpak.app-uninstall;org.freedesktop.Flatpak.runtime-uninstall;
ResultActive=auth_admin
```

### Any distro with *`policykit` >= 0.106*

Create a new file named `01‑flatpak‑sudo‑always‑password.rules` in `/⁠etc⁠/⁠polkit‑1⁠/⁠rules.d⁠⁠⁠/`

```javascript
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.Flatpak.app-install" ||
         action.id == "org.freedesktop.Flatpak.runtime-install"||
         action.id == "org.freedesktop.Flatpak.app-uninstall" ||
         action.id == "org.freedesktop.Flatpak.runtime-uninstall") &&
         subject.active == true && subject.local == true &&
         subject.isInGroup("sudo")) {
            return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
    }

    return polkit.Result.NOT_HANDLED;
});
```

---

These are direct reversions of the `policykit` rules which `flatpak` installs.

The `org.freedesktop.Flatpak.modify-repo` permission was removed ([enabled for all users by default](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/blob/a8cc112dfaf63ff2eace53cce422848c7def0f90/system-helper/org.freedesktop.Flatpak.policy.in#L104-L119)), `org.freedesktop.Flatpak.override-parental-controls` was removed (not applicable), and the returned policykit authorization type changed from `yes` back to `auth_admin`. ([`polkit` manual on auth types](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html#polkit-declaring-actions))

The `.rules` file was made by flatpak, and the `.pkla` file by Debian, based on flatpak's `.rules` file. Debian is not upgrading `policykit` beyond `0.105` for now, so they [backported the `.rules` to the old system](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825766).

[Original `.rules` file](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/blob/a8cc112dfaf63ff2eace53cce422848c7def0f90/system-helper/org.freedesktop.Flatpak.rules.in) - - - [Original `.pkla` file](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/flatpak/-/blob/3098c4d4e40520211425f6ef8f8646d5fed2560c/debian/org.freedesktop.Flatpak.pkla)

You may want to consider using `auth_admin_keep` instead, if you don't want to be asked for your password for each flatpak and each runtime in one command.